# What is the meaning of holdoff time over in systemd services?

Tags: puppet, systemctl

I have installed Puppet Enterprise on CentOS 7. I can see that several Puppet services fail to start saying holdoff time over. What does this mean?

```
Sep 03 20:50:16 l-pm1 systemd[1]: pe-puppetdb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 03 20:50:16 l-pm1 systemd[1]: Starting pe-puppetdb Service...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a service stops (or fails to start), systemd waits for a short period of time before attempting to restart it.

The amount of wait time is configurable by setting [`RestartSec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=) in the unit.

> `RestartSec=`
>
> Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service (as configured with `Restart=`). Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Defaults to 100ms.

Comment: Why should it stop? I've created a service, and see in the logs that it hits this error every 5 minutes or so, then it is logged to stop and start. I don't get why it should stop/start. Is it normal for a random service?

Comment: @jayarjo you are asking essentially "why would would software crash?" There are many possible causes.